# Is there a way to merge two or more .dex files into one .dex file using Scala?

Tags: android, scala, merge, dex, sbt-android-plugin

I am doing some hacking on Jan Berkel's SBT Android Plugin and I was wandering if there is a way to merge multiple `.dex` files into one `.dex` file that will contain all of them.

For example, if I have this:

```
classes1.dex
classes2.dex
classes3.dex
```

Is there any way to merge them using Scala (in some acceptable time) to one single `classes.dex` file that will contain all 3 of them and have a following structure:

```
classes.dex
|-- classes1/...
|-- classes2/...
\-- classes3/...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, it seems I found something.

```
import com.android.dx.io.DexBuffer
import com.android.dx.DexMerger
import com.android.dx.merge.CollisionPolicy
...
val dexA = DexBuffer(File(classes1DexFilePath))
val dexB = DexBuffer(File(classes2DexFilePath))
val dexMerger = DexMerger(dexA, dexB, CollisionPolicy.FAIL)
val dexM = dexMerger.merge()
dexM.writeTo(File(classesDexFilePath))
```

Could anyone verify this is indeed working?

Also, if this works, then merging more than 2 dex files should be the same as Max(Max(A, B), C), providing you write a method that with a prototype
`DexBuffer merge(DexBuffer dexA, DexBuffer dexB)`

Sources:
[DexMerger](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/android/tools/dx/1.7/dx-1.7-javadoc.jar!/com/android/dx/merge/DexMerger.html)
[DexBuffer](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/android/tools/dx/1.7/dx-1.7-javadoc.jar!/com/android/dx/io/DexBuffer.html)
[CollisionPolicy](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/android/tools/dx/1.7/dx-1.7-javadoc.jar!/com/android/dx/merge/CollisionPolicy.html)

Comment: How would you import the DexBuffer, DexMerger and CollisionPolicy classes? The links are empty.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way which don't need to compile from source, just use the SDK compiled jar.

```
java -cp dx.jar com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger output.dex input1.dex input2.dex
```

The dx.jar is located in Android SDK dir, like `android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\lib`.  The dex file have 64k method limit, so it can't hold so much in one dex file.

Answer (score 1):

it's working. r22 uses this way to pre-dex android-support-v4.jar and annotations.jar into dex format first. Ant then use dx.bat to merge them with the compiled .class files.

Answer (score 0):

First zip them individually like classes1.dex.zip, classes2.dex.zip, classes3.dex.zip and then run following

```
java -jar dx.jar --dex --output=classes.dex.zip classes1.dex.zip classes2.dex.zip classes3.dex.zip
```

That's it.
Now you have a classes.dex in classes.dex.zip with classes1.dex.zip classes2.dex.zip classes3.dex.zip are merged.

Comment: I tried zipping them and that didn't make any difference from when I didn't zip them so I don't think that zipping them is necessary

Answer (score 0):

#### The not outdated method

Just in case anyone stumbled on this question like I did, **all of these answers are outdated by now** (I'm only talking about the answers answered before this one in this question)

The current method to merge dex files is this:

```
d8 classes1.dex classes2.dex classes3.dex
```

`dx` has been renamed as `d8`

Now it's a **lot** simpler and cleaner

`d8` can be found (in windows) in C:\Users\$your_user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\$version\d8

You can merge any amount of dex files together, but:

**The maximum method amount of a dex file is 65,536** (Which is equal to 64K, A K is equal to a kilo which is equal to 1024)

**If you face that problem then** [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785014/the-number-of-method-references-in-a-dex-file-cannot-exceed-64k-api-17) might be helpful. The conclusion of the link was that you should use the `--multi-dex` option. So the command will look like this:

```
d8 --multi-dex classes1.dex classes2.dex classes3.dex
```

and that you need to add the line

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in the `module/build.gradle` file in the `defaultConfig` so it would look like this:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I hope this helped