# The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k API 17

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex, sugarorm

I am building an app with SugarORM Library but when I try to build the project for API 17 (didn't check for others) it shows build error.

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidVolleyVolley100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubSatyanSugar14Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMeDrakeetMaterialdialogLibrary131Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.663 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

But when I build this project for android v5.0 or above, it works fine. If I remove SugarORM gradle dependency it works fine for both devices v4.2.2 and v5.0.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html. check this

Comment: try using proguard this link https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/337 specifies using SugarORM with proguard

Comment: Just got this after upgrading to api 23. It is simply impossible to be productive with Android. Every sdk breaks stuff. Every update to AS breaks stuff. Error messages unusable. AS broken. Garbage, garbage, garbage.

Comment: @RunLoop don't loose hope....I found that android is the best platform ever developed....Moch Flexible and powerful....As you will get your hands dirty into coding....It will be fine....Every error message is useful. But need to understand messages

Comment: Don't really understand this error. I don't have 64 thousand methods or whatever referencing it on my code.

Comment: and I don't really understand this bounty, 3 years later for a question answered over and over again.

Comment: @Balaj Khan ***`One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.Just to the point and accurate answer.`*** I suggest the top (and accepted) answer !.

Answer (score 528, accepted):

You have too many methods. There can only be **65536 methods for dex**.

As suggested you can use the [**multidex support**](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Just add these lines in the `module/build.gradle`:

```
android {
   
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'  //with androidx libraries
  //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  //with support libraries
  
}
```

Or if using `module/build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
android {
    // other properties

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")  // with androidx libraries
    // implementation("com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3")  // with support libraries
}
```

Also in your `Manifest` add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
        <application
            ...
            android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

            <!-- If you are using support libraries use android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" -->

            <!--If you are using your own custom Application class then extend -->
            <!--MultiDexApplication and change above line as-->
            <!--android:name=".YourCustomApplicationClass"> -->

            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

If you are using your own `Application` class, change the parent class from `Application` to `MultiDexApplication`.
If you can't do it, in your Application class override the `attachBaseContext` method with:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Another solution is to try to remove unused code with **ProGuard** - Configure the [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) settings for your app to run ProGuard and ensure you have shrinking enabled for release builds.

Comment: @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
   super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
   MultiDex.install(this);
   }   also override

Comment: Cmd-clicking MultiDexApplication, I see the decompiled .class file already performs exactly the attachBaseContext() override you describe. So it won't be necessary to override that again I guess..

Comment: What if I don't have too many methods. I don't have that much methods on my app. I believe that it doesn't even reach that.

Comment: Tell me about the package entry in the manifest tag. Will that not replace my own applications package and cause problems?

Comment: I only did these two parts: "multiDexEnabled true" and compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0', in my build.grandle file. I did not have to change anything in my manifest file nor do the other things you mentioned about overriding attachBaseContext, etc. But your solution fixed the problem for me! Thanks.

Comment: @NeonWarge Probably because of your dependencies. Perhaps, you have included the entire Google Play Services? Check this [answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27589562/2304737)

Comment: thanks, I just add  " multiDexEnabled true" and  "compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0" to my "build.gradle" and solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for share, my problem solved with your suggestion.

Comment: I am working on flutter and adding only multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig works for me thnx

Answer (score 203):

In android/app/build.gradle

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 23

 buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dkm.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

### Put this inside your defaultConfig:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

> it works for me

Comment: This is for Lollipop or higher only isn't it?

Comment: It makes the build successful, but app crashes after launch.

Comment: in have same problem in my project but when set multidex as true the problems not fix until i enable multidex in module application of project

Answer (score 26):

## Change the app level build.gradle :

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 23

 buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dkm.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

it worked for me.

Comment: yes, it is a old issue, but for last versions of API we need only `multiDexEnabled` option, without dependencies or manifest file changes

Comment: Let's hopefully get this to the top then.

Answer (score 22):

I got this error message because while coding my project auto update compile version in my `build.gradle` file :

```
android {
    ...
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' }
```

Solve it by correcting the version:

```
android {
        ...
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        ...
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: I'm creating simple app, which worked fine until I tried following the Google Map Objects tutorial.  Suddenly I wasn't able to compile anymore.  This solution has fixed that for me.  How on earth did you work it out?

Comment: This method luckily worked because new compile libraries have too many methods (exceeds 65536), and old libraries doesn't. So it is just a quick fix, sooner or later you should fix by adding multidex support like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me:

This happens because there are too many unused methods.
Most of these methods are coming from included libraries in your build.gradle

Use minify and shrink resources to fix this with gradle and clean up your code at the same time.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

This error can also occur when you load all google play services apis when you only using afew.

As stated by google:"In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit.

From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app."

For example when your app needs play-services-maps ,play-services-location .You need to add only the two apis in your build.gradle file at app level as show below:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
```

Instead of:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
```

For full documentation and list of google play services apis click [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)

Answer (score 16):

When your app references exceed **65,536** methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture

**Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**

Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21) use the Dalvik runtime for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this limitation, you can add the multidex support library to your project:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

**Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**

Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading multiple DEX files from APK files. Therefore, if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher, you do ***not need the multidex*** support library.

**Avoid the 64K limit**

- Remove unused code with ProGuard - Enable code shrinking

**Configure multidex in app for**

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21 
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
 ...
}
```

if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex support library

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15 
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Override the Application class, change it to extend *MultiDexApplication* (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

add to the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="MyApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11):

I have been facing the same problem and for multidex support, you have to keep in mind the **minSdkVersion** of your application. If you are using **minSdkVersion 21** or above then just write **multiDexEnabled true** like this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId *******************
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

It works for me and if you are using **minSdkVersion** below 21 (below **lolipop**) then you have to do two extra simple things

**1.** First add this dependency

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

in your build.gradle.

**2.** Last and second add one this below line to your application in manifest

> android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Bingo then it will work in the lower version also..:)
Happy coding

Answer (score 9):

add this to avoid multidex issue for react native or any android project

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }  
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  //with support libraries
  //implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'  //with androidx libraries
```

Answer (score 7):

**

### For Unity Game Developers

**

If anyone comes here because this error showed up in their Unity project, Go to File->Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Player. go to Publishing Settings and under the Build tab, enable "Custom Launcher Gradle Template". a path will be shown under that text. go to the path and add multiDexEnabled true like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
    targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
    applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
    ndk {
        abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
    }
    versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
    versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a side comment, Before adding support for multidex - make sure you are not adding unnecessary dependencies.

For example [In the official Facebook analytics guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/quickstart-list/android/)

They clearly state that you should add the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

which is actually the **entire** FacebookSDK - so if you need for example just the Analytics you need to replace it with:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.+'
```

[Facebook partial SDK options](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/)

Comment: Totally agree. In my case for example, I just needed the "login with facebook" button and was using the entire facebook sdk. I've replaced it with `facebook-core` and `facebook-login` and the error has gone.

Answer (score 4):

I changed my minSdkVersion to 20 and it worked for me. Check https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle for more details

Answer (score 3):

For me Upgrading Gradle works.Look for update at [Android Website](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)
then add it in your build.gradle (Project) like this

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha4'   
          ....
    }
```

then sync project with gradle file plus it might be happened sometimes because of java.exe (in my case) just force kill java.exe from task manager in windows then re run program

Answer (score 3):

Can also try this :

```
android{
    .
    .
    // to avoid DexIndexOverflowException
    dexOptions {
       jumboMode true
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do this, it works:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.maps"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you can enable "Instant Run" on Android Studio to get multidex support.