# The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K

Tags: android

I took a new android project. It ran fine on device. Then I added -

```
dependencies {
   ....
   ....
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
```

Now when i try to run the app, it gives -

```
Error- The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
```

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785014/the-number-of-method-references-in-a-dex-file-cannot-exceed-64k-api-17

Comment: There's so much info regarding 64k limit online, I can't believe you didn't find anything useful before posting to SO.

Comment: Read this, http://jakewharton.com/play-services-is-a-monolith/ and https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71#.rqu4x1qos

Comment: @Egor you are correct ..there's so much info regarding 64k limit online

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to deal with this.

1. Enable `MultiDex` :

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 22
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
            targetSdkVersion 22

            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
   }
   ```
2. Use specific play services needed in your application instead of whole package as described here:

   [Add dependency for specific Play service from this list](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Answer (score 0):

That mean your method in your project exceed 65535.
You can see this:

[Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Will load all the methods and packages from the google play services. This is actually a wrong way to add a dependency. If you want to use a particular thing from google play services, then add only that particular package.

For eg: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'`

This will load only location package and hence it will decrease the method references.