# I need to solve this error in Android

Tags: android

Error:

> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: use multidexEnabled

Comment: multidexEnabled is workarround. Maybe, based on jour API you need to install Java 1.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k API 17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785014/the-number-of-method-references-in-a-dex-file-cannot-exceed-64k-api-17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your Gradle do this**

```
 defaultConfig {
    .....
    ......
    multiDexEnabled true
    .......
}

dependencies {
 .........
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
.............
```

}
*And in your manifest in your* **Application tag**

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    .......
   .........
```

**Happy to help**