# when try to run application get error?

Tags: android

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]

> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It
>   currently has approximately 910 MB. For faster builds, increase the
>   maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB. To do
>   this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project
>   gradle.properties. For more information see
>   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
>   Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed
>   64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 4 mins 31.676 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: you can try the links provided to you for best possible solution, will surely help

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785014/the-number-of-method-references-in-a-dex-file-cannot-exceed-64k-api-17