# google gms:play service conflict with firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to add firebase-messaging in my project where i am already using google maps. so when i add firebase dependecy

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

i got following error.

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

how can i solve this issue 
here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.edesign.astutesol.sallaticustomerapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.+'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'

}
```

these are google dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

Comment: Hi. Have you seen posts discussing about the error like this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36785014/4625829)?

Comment: @AL.  yes i tried multiDexEnabled but its also not helping.

Comment: Remove this dependency if not required `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`. Because, it has 79958 method count.

Comment: i need this for maps. i am using latlong in my application.

Comment: Then you need to use this one....  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'

Comment: okay let me try this one.

Comment: it would be better always to keep apk method count below 65K.

Answer (score 2):

enable multidex in your default config.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.edesign.astutesol.sallaticustomerapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: i tried multiDexEnabled but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

If enabling multidex support hasn't worked for you it can be because you might have defined custom application class for your app. What's the application name in your manifest file? If you have defined a custom application class by extending Application (say for example to integrate ACRA, or google analytics) then you will have to override attachBaseContext method.

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**short answer:** remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`

---

You should not have the following line in your **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

that line will include ALL the google libraries in your applications, which will exceed the method limit (the error you reported) and will make your app big without benefits.

You should include only the sub library that you need.

Example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1
```

is ok because you are including only the **-auth** parth of the library.