# After renaming package my project showing error while building in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, package

After renaming package my project showing error while building in android.

I used this: [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package?rq=1)     for renaming my project and after that it started getting these errors:

```
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

then i used https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
for resolving first error but that also didn't work.

So i restarted Android Studio and then again tried to build but same error occured.

then i tried to undo back to old package name but nothing good happened.....
please help!...

Thanks in advance......

Comment: enable multidex in your app level gradle file

Comment: can you add the changes that you have done to resolve `multidex` error

Comment: go through this link it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/36786721/7604342

Comment: please post gradle as well as manifest in this question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42672402/7399521 check this i hope its help you

Comment: Project builds successfully, but when i try to run the app on device it shows the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**firstly add build.gradle below code**

```
dependencies {//just add below one in dependency
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' ....//no change your old jar file.....}
```

**then**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your pkg name"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 6
    versionName "v2.5.2.2"
    multiDexEnabled true // just add it
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
dexOptions { //add it
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}}
```

**in manifest file**

```
<application
android:name=".Education_multidex" //add what ur create java file
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/rvms_education_luncher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> ....</application>
```

**then create and add one java file like Education_multidex.java**

```
public class Education_multidex extends MultiDexApplication {/* @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}*/}
```

**finaly build your app then add import some lib in above java file**

Answer (score 0):

can you please just add below code in your `build.gradle`

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

and in your `ApplicationClass` add below code.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

I think there's a separate way to raise the heap limit of the dexing operation. Add this to your `android` closure in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Now it gives error :              `Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: It also took very long time to build :`Information:Total time: 5 mins 41.435 secs`