# com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, > 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I run in my device its working properly But while building apk in android studio its showing error:

> Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the
>   'Messages' view

Here is the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

Comment: What is error? Please post your error.

Comment: `you can find the errors in the Messages view` have you checked the messages view?

Comment: Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view

Comment: show the errors from the messages view

Comment: At least you need to post some code and error message to resolve your error.

Comment: Try looking through the exception stacktrace in if you can find one in Logcat. Chances are you will be able to figure the problem out sooner or later, once you try debugging. Try googling the main exception. If not, please update the question to include the error stacktrace present in the messages view.

Comment: k I will upload error page mr AMIRSH kAKADIYA

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved after i removed jar file from my project. it seems that one of the jar files inside my project was using an google play services

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this morning. You've likely hit the upper limit on how many methods you can have in a dex file (by having lots of dependencies).

The solution is to enable multiDex; [This other SO answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36786721/4571656) explains it far better than I ever could.