# Gradle build did not finished

Tags: java, android

I am getting these 2 errors while building my android project and I don't know what they mean.

Error#1:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

Error#2:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable multi-dex support. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36786721/5137352) for more details and instructions how to enable it.