# getting ".dex file cannot exceed 64K" error without any change in code(without touching any code not even gradle scripts)

Tags: android, dex

I have not made any code change from last successfully building repo but I still se this

```
Error:Gradle: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
```

Can it be due to update of sdk,build tools or some android studio/gradle plugin ?
my minSdkVersion is 15

**Note: this is more specific to situation it happens without touching any code not even gradle scripts**

Comment: It can be due to any library or sdk upgrade.  Look into multidex as a solution

Comment: how to live without going multidex. I want to keep the app lightweight

Comment: Cut features. Reduce your function count. Use profits to remove unused functions

Comment: just curious can you tell me in reality what percent of the quality apps that people use on day to day basis(eg whatsapp,snapchat,facebook,twitter,amazon) are built without going multidex?

Comment: Those?  All of those are multidex.  Facebook invented it I'm fairly sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k API 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785014/the-number-of-method-references-in-a-dex-file-cannot-exceed-64k-api-17)

Comment: this was more specific to ask what are all the situation it can happen without even touching the code.