# Problem encountered in installing react-native

Tags: react-native

This is a react-native installation issue:

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> C:\Users\eshas\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android

Comment: run **chmod 755 android/gradlew** inside your app root folder
then run **react-native run-android**

Comment: Ref this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776936/command-failed-gradlew-bat-installdebug

Answer (score 0):

You need to install AndroidStudio and Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Soluton:

> `chmod 755 android/gradlew`