# I can't run my Android app (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native, android-sdk-manager

I installed android SDk but When I run react-native run-android.
 I added ANDROID_HOME to system/user PATH ...I encounter the following error.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug
>   -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776936/command-failed-gradlew-bat-installdebug) should be of help. Happy coding

Comment: Thank you @OsamaD.