# What should I need to do to run React Native CLi App?

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error while I used this command: "npx react-native run-android[image: I have attached the image below. Please help me if anyone has any idea regarding this or where I gone wrong]"

Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

Comment: Try some of the options listed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776936/command-failed-gradlew-bat-installdebug/54778900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not properly build and also there were some libraries missing out. That's why this error came