# Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, android-emulator

This is done in VS Code. I have seen TONS OF similar posts, so this is a common occurence. I think it maybe stems from a misunderstanding of gradle builds so any help is greatly appreciated! I created a react-native app following their CLI guide. Running the command react-native android did not work, and I followed a stack overflow solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844245/how-solve-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-reflection-reflectionc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776936/command-failed-gradlew-bat-installdebug). The command works, and an emulator is created properly, without having to go into android studio and starting it from there. I do a little bit of coding, and then want to install some extensions. I install flow, and babel E6, boom react-native run-android no longer works. A workaround is to start from android studio. I have followed countless stackoverflow answers on the same question as this title, example [gradlew.bat install debug error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776936/command-failed-gradlew-bat-installdebug). I gave up and decided to start a new project, boom run-android doesn't work as it seems is standard. I change my gradle version as per the first link, and the command works now for this second project.

```
Gradlew --version of 1st project: 
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          15.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.1+9-18)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

gradlew help of 1st project:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

gradlew build --warning-mode=all of first project:
The BuildListenr.buildStarted(Gradle) method has been deprecated
Internal API constructor DefaultDomainObjectSet(Class<T>) has been deprecated.
Injecting the input artifact of a transform as a File has been dprecated.
```

So from my understanding on their troubleshooting site, the issue lies with one of the requested tasks rather than a configuration step.

Furthermore I have tried disabling the flow and babel extensions, as well as remove the added config files that weren't included in the react-native init app. I have also tried changing the package.json file to the same as the working second project. Even if a solution is found for this project, I am still curious as to why everytime I start a react-native project I have to change the gradle version in gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties. Any help or input is greatly appreciated.