# Error "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0" When I do gradle lint

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hello I am trying execute `./gradlew lint`, and I am getting the following message:

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

I did remove all gradles from .gradle/daemon, but gradlew download the version 4.4.1.

The question is how can update to the 6.0.0 or how can solve this?

Thanks

I check this [Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with), but the answers of this doesn't work for me.

In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` I have the following

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

But in http://services.gradle.org/distributions/ the last version is 5.4.1.

Comment: Did you try `--warning-mode all`?  Incidentally, I get this when I use `addCucumberSuite 'foo'`, so it may not be anything in your script/config directly, but something it relies on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with)

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates the usage of APIs that are considered deprecated in the Gradle 5.x line and which will be removed in Gradle 6.x.

Upgrading to Gradle 6.x (not yet released at this time) will not make the message go away, instead it will most likely break your build.

The way to make such warning disappear is to track down the usages, replacing them with the new APIs recommended.

As for tracking them down, use the `--warning-mode=all` flag when invoking Gradle to have details about the deprecations.