# Build first java project with gradle in intellij idea,Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build

Tags: java, gradle

Run my first app(Hello world)  from IntelliJ idea using Gradle, it runs but in console there is a warning "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0". I have no dependencies in **build.gradle** file, where I can change compile to implementation mode?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't see your screen. There's no way we can guess why you get that warning and what you should change if you don't post your gradle build file. Run with `--warning-mode=all`, and you'll know why you get this warning. The output should be in your question, too. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: thank u for answer. Could you please tell where i should set --warning-mode= all?

Comment: In your command line, where you execute the build: `./gradlew build --warning-mode=all`

Comment: Post everything that needs to be posted **as text** in the question itself. Not as links to images.

Comment: In this case, there is no problem: E:\devel\JavaLearn\sandbox> gradlew build --warning-mode=all

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
E:\devel\JavaLearn\sandbox>

Comment: Then you're not using anything deprecated. The IDE is probably using something deprecated, but not you.

Comment: Most probably there is nothing for you to do here. It's not about your code. Some plugins you are using may be using deprecated APIs, but their authors will have to fix that before next major Gradle release. Just make sure to use the latest third-party plugins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with)

Answer (score 1):

One way to see these warnings is to put the following into `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.warning.mode=all
```

Then re-import into IntelliJ.  This was the only mechanism I was able to find to show these values.

There may be some other mechanism that enables warnings only for the wrapper being launched by IntelliJ, but if so I didn't find it.