# Not able to add dependency through build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle

Whenever i am trying to add dependency in the project through build.gradle , it is not able to add dependency. Instead it throws warning as

Could not resolve: junit:junit:4.12

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 1s

I have tried every hook to resolve it, but was not able to. 
Please find below build.gradle file which i am using

---

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

group 'practice'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with and run your gradle build command with extra parameters. You'll get more info what got deprecated and you'll have a better idea how to resolve your deprecation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per mvnrepository.com, for Gradle it has been mentioned as

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

The link is given below.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12

If it does not work, try to add the repository as given below.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

junit version 12 also available in maven repo, you can check following link.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/

Sometimes, we have seen sporadic issue because of corrupt file.
You can delete the .gradle file and you can rerun with command like `gradle clean build`.