# Flutter Android build output is wrong

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk, android-app-bundle

I have an app that I upgraded to build with Flutter 2. I'm still to do the null-safety stuff, but one step at a time.

When I do builds (both release and debug) the `apk`'s and `aab`'s get output to the wrong location and (in the case of `aab`'s) this causes flutter to throw up at the end.

In this screenshot you will see the output gets generated to the `android/app/build` folder, this is not correct

[image: build folder in android]

In the case of building `apk`'s it also generates it to the `build/app/outputs` folder which is better but still not 100% as it should be `build/app/outputs/apk/nonprod/release/app-nonprod-release.apk`

[image: build folder in root]

So my app has two flavors [ prod | nonprod ] and I do builds for `aab`'s and `apk`'s on both release and debug builds.

here is also the output of al 4 builds (all on the `nonprod` flavor)
[image]

#### Some gradle info

- ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
- flavor config

```
    flavorDimensions "environment"

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
        nonprod {
            dimension "environment"
            versionNameSuffix "-test"
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        }
    }
```

So how do I solve this to generate the artefacts to the correct folder

`build/app/outputs/apk/{flavor}/{buildType}/app-{flavor}-{buildType}.apk`

and

`build/app/outputs/bundle/{flavor}{buildType}/app-{flavor}-{buildType}.aab`

and not fail completely on appbundle's

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why dont you try using android module. Open Android dictory inside the android studio and try building aab.

Comment: @rajkavadia. Thanks. But running locally on development workstation is not a problem. This needs to build in a CI/CD pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as part of my migration to Flutter 2 I made a mistake.

in `android/build.gradle` where the `subprojects` are defined I tried being clever and combined them into a single `subprojects` block. This caused the problem.

It's important that if you currently have two separate blocks, they are kept separate, like so

```
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

When generating a new flutter project it will in fact be generated with a single block.

```
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

Don't try to use that in an older one.

Credit to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414006/2181352