# flutter release apk error :Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, release

I can not release my app any more .
I'm using AndroidStudio 4.0 and flutter sdk version 1.17.5 .
I had been released my app  two times last month but now I really don't know whats the reason of error.
when I type `flutter build apk --release` in terminal then these errors occure:

```
        Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:profileRuntimeClasspath'.

   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: ....\build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar.

         > Failed to transform '....\build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: FileNotFoundException, message: ....\build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar (The system cannot find the path specified). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

           Please file a bug at http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323.



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 42s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           43.4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: run with verbose like this > flutter run --release -v

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394034/flutter-can-not-build-android-apk

Comment: Check out this link for a detailed explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394034/flutter-can-not-build-android-apk/65354542#65354542

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If error is about `profile/libs.jar` , do following in terminal :

```
flutter build apk --profile
```

and then

```
flutter build apk --release
```

solves the issue.

and if error is about  `debug/libs.jar`

```
flutter build apk --debug
```

and then

```
flutter build apk --release
```

will solve the problem

Comment: That's what I get after running `flutter build apk --profile`: `Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under ~/dev/flutter/discover_rudy/build, but the tool couldn't find it`

Answer (score 17):

For me worked this way only:

```
First: flutter build apk --debug
```

- 

```
Then: flutter build apk --profile
```

- 

```
In the end: flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: while @Zahra answer is leading, this answer is the only one that helped me. make sure to do exactly those steps at the same order.

Answer (score 15):

I have upgraded my gradle build tools 3.5.0 -> 4.0.1.
After that I am not was not able to make release apk.
Looks like upgrading gradle build tools broke some lints.

Below solution worked for me

Go in android folder->app->open build.gradle fine
Search for lintOptions and add **checkReleaseBuilds false**
example:

```
lintOptions {
  disable 'InvalidPackage'
  checkReleaseBuilds false //Insert this line
}
```

Comment: make sure to move lintOptions to the android section of your Gradle file: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/LintOptions but also it seems not to be recommended approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098494/applintvitalrelease-error-when-generating-signed-apk

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to add the flavor name as well following this sequence:

```
flutter build apk --debug --flavor <dev-flavor>
flutter build apk --debug --flavor <prod-flavor>
flutter build apk --profile --flavor <dev-flavor>
flutter build apk --profile --flavor <prod-flavor>
flutter build apk --release --flavor <dev-flavor>
flutter build apk --release --flavor <prod-flavor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
1- flutter build apk --debug

2- flutter build apk --profile
3-  flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: You have just copy paste from @wahid anvary. Next time add additional information to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the problem may have already been solved, however I did not like the way the proposed solutions propose to solve the problem. In my view, the following is a more correct solution:

Make sure everything here is correct:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#shrinking-your-code-with-r8

Be sure to check each parameter and version used. This works in all my apps and without gambling.

Check if in `android\app\build.gradle` is as below:

```
buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           minifyEnabled true
           shrinkResources true
           useProguard true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
```

Check if in `android\build.gradle` is as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}
```

Check if in `android\gradle.properties` is as below:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Check if in `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` is as below:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Now you can run the commands: `flutter run apk` or `flutter run appbundle` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps if anyone encounter same issue

1. Go to Terminal write following lines
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `flutter build apk --profile`
5. `flutter build apk --release`

hope it will solve the issue