# Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'. > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: flutter, debugging, gradle, release, libs

I am getting this error when running 'flutter run --release' in the terminal. I am looking if someone can give suggestion to resolve this issue. I tried many solutions found in internet, but it did not word. Thanks.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\mn\AndroidStudioProjects\myport\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.
> > Transform's input file does not exist: C:\Users\mn\AndroidStudioProjects\myport\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/iss
> ues/158753935)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     110.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix this by upgrading your version of gradle to at least 7.2

Kindly confirm if updating your gradle-wrapper.properties and build.gradle to the following resolves the issue.

in gradle-wrapper.properties update your distributionUrl to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

and in android/build.gradle change the gradle version from 4.1.0 to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines to your android>app>build.gradle

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 28

lintOptions {

    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    //Put the following line
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    //abortOnError false
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot <3. It works finally

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps in this [link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720395/flutter-release-apk-error-execution-failed-for-task-applintvitalrelease)
I run
First: flutter build apk --debug
Then: flutter build apk --profile
In the end: flutter build apk --release