# Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease' Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, lintvitalrelease

I tried building my flutter application to APk but keep recieving this error.

` Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':url_launcher_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.

> Failed to transform bcprov-jdk18on-1.72.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.72) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Crusader.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk18on\1.72\d8dc62c28a3497d29c93fee3e71c00b27dff41b4\bcprov-jdk18on-1.72.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\Crusader.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk18on\1.72\d8dc62c28a3497d29c93fee3e71c00b27dff41b4\bcprov-jdk18on-1.72.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)`

I have tried flutter clean and upgrading the gradle but it isn't working

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/62720395/8144311 help?