# Run pure Java class in Android Studio 3.6

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Prior to Android Studio 3.6 it was possible for me to run a pure Java Class without any configuration. After the update of Android Studio to version 3.6 I'm not able anymore to run a pure Java Class. There are multiple things which really getting on my nerves because of AS 3.6....

As a barebone example

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello")
   }
}
```

As I said prior to AS 3.6 I could run this. But now, I get the following Exception

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:Test.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
```

Comment: you might have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with

Comment: I just ran this exact code and mine worked. And I am using 3.6. Try naming your class something other than Test?

Comment: @Brokoth I tried it with several names without any success.

Comment: @Sceada Are you running the class specifically(right clicking anywhere in file then running that file) ?

Comment: @Brokoth Yes, I tried different things to run the class. I also tried to edit the run configuration. 
Well I guess the problem lies in my project gradle file. Actually I have no idea why, but another problem (Data-Binding) was gradle related, after the AS Update.

Answer (score -4):

Check your android manifest and make sure some activity define to launcher