# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0. I get error in image fragement

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See

Comment: So have you seen the deprecation warnings by running gradle with `--warning-mode=all`?

Comment: yes, I have seen that warnings.

Comment: Can you post these warnings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with)