# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle X

Tags: android, react-native, realm, npm-install, gradlew

I want install [realm](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#getting-started) localDb with **react-native** but after install this package in `npm` project not run with this command `react-native run-android`,

> `Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED` I don't know what is mean this error !!!

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

### Project Setting

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.olyaaqarat"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

---

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
    }
}
```

---

```
$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.2
```

**Android Gradle version**
`Gradle 6.7`

**Test Device**

> Real devoice android 9

I look this answer but not  help me !!!
[Deprecated Gradle features were....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with)

Comment: Please match your Gradle plugin with the correct Gradle version see here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try updating your dependencies gradle. I've been using 4.0.1 and it's been working pretty well with the newer version of react native.

```
    dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
}
```

It should work with your current build tooks and sdk versions.