# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug' react native on visual studio code

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan
  to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  I installed react-native using `npx react-native init mobile` and after installing all the dependencies and try running with `yarn android` which ran `react-native run-android`.

I keep getting this error below;

- Get more help at *https://help.gradle.org*

BUILD FAILED in 26s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: *https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup*. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
**Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081**

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit *https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run* for documentation about this command.

After updating my local.properties in the android folder with the `sdk.dir = C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

I am still getting the error above? Pls, how can I resolve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem by macos and resolve installing jdk8.

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
npx react-native run android
```