# Grandle Build Error In Unity. I have a unity grandle build error look the console?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am getting these errors:

[image]

[image]

Please Help!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. I'm pretty sure you are not using that language nowadays (if so .. yikes!).

Comment: I would start digging into [`Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with) ...