# How to integrate GitHub Pull Request Coverage Status in Jenkinsfile

Tags: gradle, jenkins, github-actions, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

I want to integrate the code coverage tool Jacoco with threshold percent of coverage into PRs. For that, I am taking the example of  [Using the plugin in a Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-coverage-reporter-plugin#using-the-plugin-in-a-jenkinsfile) of this repo as a reference https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-coverage-reporter-plugin. I want code coverage to be part of this `pr-merge` task as shown in this image:

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this? I want to know where to add this code in my Jenkinsfile for the desired result.

Comment: Are you using Jenkins alongside GitHub Actions?

Comment: No, I am not using GHA now. I am simply using Jenkinsfile now for the integration. https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-pr-coverage-status/ - please check Simple Multibranch Pipeline example.

Comment: I am getting this error after adding those two stages in my Jenkinsfile : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named CompareCoverageAction

Comment: @Azeem Can you please tell me how can I find this https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-coverage-reporter/#plugin-content-using-the-plugin window on Jenkins after installing and configuring the plugin?

Comment: I haven't used it before so I won't be able to guide you. You might want to experiment on your own while waiting for the right responses.