# Fastlane build fails on Flutter while building android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, fastlane

Recently I tried to automate my deployment flow of my flutter apps with **fastlane** so I setup **fastlane** in my project with all the necessary configuration but I'm getting a problem when I run **fastlane android deploy_beta_staging**  command to deploy the staging version of the app to firebase distribution but i kept getting this error at the end. I attached the picture of the error below. any help will be appreciated

- I have made research on how to fix it some information i got says
  that the problem is usually peculiar to those using the new apple
  silicon chip which is what i'm using.
- I tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with) and [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20493) but none seems to fix my problem[image]
  **here are the tools i'm using**
- fastlane 2.214.0(from brew)
- flutter 3.10.5
- Dart 3.0.5
- Pc apple M1 Pro

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.214.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:153:in
> `shell_error!': \e[31m[!] Shell command exited with exit status 1
> instead of 0. (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneShellError)

Comment: Looking at the gradle error at the top, this is a problem with your build configuration, not fastlane itself. I think you need to follow the steps on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51610775/1445366 to see which feature is incompatible with Gradle 8

Comment: Also, if possible, please replace the screenshot with the text formatted in a code block. It makes the questions more easily searchable and also readable by users with visual disabilities.

Comment: okay thanks for the response,  i went as far as upgrading my gradle from 7.4 to 8.0 hoping that the error will be fixed but i'm still getting an error saying that something is incompatible with Gradle 9

Comment: The error message means you're using an old Gradle feature which is no longer supported in the new versions. So no amount of upgrading Gradle is going to fix this. You need to identify the incompatible feature and stop using it.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response i will try and figure out the incompatible feature

Comment: Thanks for your help i was able to fix it by doing what you said, i discovered that jcenter() was the problem as it's already deprecated and i was using it in my project , everything works after removing it and downgrading my java version from 20 to 18