# My flutter app is not displaying in chrome when launched with no errors and when run to my android it gives me errors

Tags: flutter

The error says the number of method references in dex file cannot exceed 64.
I have tried changing the emulator I used and also changed how I launch the app, but no display still.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k API 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785014/the-number-of-method-references-in-a-dex-file-cannot-exceed-64k-api-17)

Comment: Hi Please try to ask a question in the question itself, not in answer.

Comment: ok apologize, am new here

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
minSdkVersion = 21
```

or higher in your gradle file and tell us if it fixes

The problem is with the multidex file of android.

Setting minSdkVersion to 21 or higher enable by default multidex. If you want to keep down the minsdk, you could also follow the answer that was given here:
[How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Comment: it gave me this error;  What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/user/Desktop/payzfast_live/and
roid/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 69; Attribute "name
" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified
for element "application"., it says build failed, gradletask assembledebug faled

Comment: where can i find this also registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.